# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular2-routing, plunker, angular2-router3

I'm trying to reproduce my problem with Angular2 router but i cannot create a working copy of my project in Plunker.

Here is my try: https://plnkr.co/edit/1lpoYP4qlBZLuqZHW7Ft

I used the following line of code in the `index.html` file to make the routes paths working with the run environment of Plunker and with my `''` default paths.

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

Why i'm stilling get this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You have a small typo in your plnkr:

   loadChildren: 'app/**fist**-section.module#FirstSectionModule' }

   might be **first** ;)
2. There's still another problem: Even childrens need an empty `''`-path. So instead of writing

`children: [
     { path: 'first-section', loadChildren: 'app/first-section.module#FirstSectionModule' }
 ]`

you should add an empty path and redirect to the `first-section`-path like this:

```
children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'first-section'},
    { path: 'first-section', loadChildren: 'app/fist-section.module#FirstSectionModule' }
]
```

Here is the corrected plnkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/9fMwx0?p=preview

---

### Update Angular 2.4.1:

I noticed that with the latest version of angular (2.4.1) it is not necessary any more to use an empty path for the children routes.

I updated the plunker with the latest angular 2.4.1 version: [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/AoeY0S?p=preview). The sample is running without an empty path right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! Anyway as you can see the main app component is loaded twice. Can you have a look again at the (updated) Plunker? https://plnkr.co/edit/AB6ac11Ne50Tj9zuzf57

Comment: The problem is, that you have defined the `AppComponent` for your `''`-path. So it will load the childrens into your root `<router-outlet>` in which you have your whole app running. You need to create another component, I named it `StartComponent`: See the updated plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5f7Q0Pgji64l5GauDqMX?p=preview

Comment: What could i change in the paths to make it working without adding a new "container" component?

Comment: In addition, when i click on "Sub Page" i would like to see it under "First Section container"... but it loads at the topper level (it replaces "First Section container" instead of appear under it).

Comment: You cannot get it working without a new container component. If you set the "AppComponent" for the `''`-path, it will replace the current component which is currently loaded into the parent router-outlet. So you replace the whole AppComponent with e.g. the "First Section Comp.". Try it out :) But you will go better to add another component.

if you want to see the sub pages under the "First Section container" you have to create childrens again ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JcMZSrYAH1WDnViP7Mxh?p=preview)).

Comment: Thank you for your support, i really appreciate it. I have updated my Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/WT9dc6oYOVn5Waw8dmwk) and i added a second section. As you can see the sub-pages of the second section loads the sub-pages of the first section. The paths should be the following: `/first-section/sub-page` and `/first-section/sub-page2` for the First Section and `/second-section/sub-page` and `/second-section/sub-page2` for the Second Section. How to reach this?

Comment: All you need to do is to transform the absolute routes into relative routes (corrected):

`export class SecondSectionComponent {
    menus: Array<any> = [
        { title: 'Second Sub Page', path: 'sub-page'},
        { title: 'Second Sub Page 2', path: 'sub-page-2'}
    ]
}`

I removed the `/` before the paths so the router stays in the current `<router-outlet`> and navigates to the `sub-page`.

https://plnkr.co/edit/GpCwUzsF08pTlEtGPgNP?p=preview

Comment: alternatively you work with absolute routes like this: `path: '/second-section/sub-page'`

Comment: Your latest Plunker doesn't work... Second Section doesn't load.

Comment: For me it's working... it needs a moment to load the second section, dont know why it's not working for you... but I postet all of my changes above so you can use this approach.

Comment: I solved my problems with this answer, using Angular 6